# Doubt in displacement time graph for a body moving with constant, negative velocity

Tags: kinematics, velocity, displacement

This is a displacement - time graph of a body having constant, negative velocity.
[image]

As we can see, the angle $θ$ (in anti - clockwise direction) is greater than $270^\circ$, and lesser than $360^\circ$, indicating that the slope $m$ or velocity $v$ is $-ve$ (as $\tan(θ)$ is $-ve$).

However, upon doing further research, the agreed upon graph looks like this:

[image]

In this case the slope $m$ is $-ve$ as well. Are both graphs correct? Or is the first graph wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only essential difference between the two graphs is that the first one is showing displacement $x$ against time, so it starts with $x=0$ at $t=0$ (because displacement is measured from the starting position), whereas the second is showing position against time, and the point at which the position is counted as zero is arbitrary. So neither graph is wrong - they are just measuring different things on the vertical axis.

The important similarity is that both graphs have the same slope, so give you the same value for the velocity of the object.

Answer (score 0):

They are essentially the same graphs with the first graph starting at the origin, ie position is zero when time is zero, and for the second graph the position is not zero when the clock starts.

You could also use the angle $\theta'$, which will be negative, to find the gradient.

[image]